# How do I display customized information in a modal using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently creating a modal form as part of an ASP.NET MVC project.

The page displays a list of people, these people items are associated with a button.  When the button is pressed next to a person, I want to display this person's name in the model.

My issue is getting the record that the button is associated with, so that I can display data from that particular record.  I have tried using an integer, which increments on each record.  Here is my pseudo-code:

```
    list = ordered list of records from People table in database
    int i = 0;
    foreach item in list
          ..display info..
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_@i">Add Action</button>
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_@i" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
                  ..
          <div class="modal-body">
                  ... ??? 
          i++;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is name add a data attribute to the button.

```
<button data-name="@name" data-toggle=.....> <!-- not sure what Razor syntax is for @name-->
```

Then an element in modal to insert name

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="modal-name"></div>
</div>
```

And add a click handler

```
$('button['data-toggle="modal"]).click(function(){
     $( $(this).data('target') +' .modal-name').text( $(this).data('name'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so the click handler is a script, and the 'target', 'model-name' and 'name' correspond to my modal attributes?

Comment: name comes from your server side list, the other items are shown in the html. Not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Since the pseudo-code you've shown implies that you're using Bootstrap, I'd suggest saving yourself some time and using [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com).

This example will make a few assumptions:

1. Your model (the `@Model` your view will reference) will be a collection of `Person` objects.
2. Your `Person` has a string `Name` property.
3. You want to show the dialog by clicking a "button" of some sort.

**Example:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>

@foreach(var person in Model)
{
    <a href="#" data-name="@person.Name" class="view-detail">View person</a>
}

<script src="~/scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){

        $('a.view-detail').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // cancel the navigation event

            var name = $(this).data('name');
            bootbox.alert(name);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Bootbox generates the necessary markup for showing a Bootstrap modal, so you don't have to have a dialog template sitting around in your page source. This example uses the simplest form of the Bootbox dialogs; you can do quite a bit more, which is [covered in the documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html).